# bootstrap-toggle JQuery plugin undefined using Webpack + Typescript

Tags: jquery, typescript, webpack

I'm trying to use the JQuery plugin [bootstrap-toggle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-toggle) with my Webpacked Typescript project but each time I try and call it, it gives me a `is not a function` error and the actual handle is undefined.

I noticed that webpack wasn't including the module so I put an import for it at the top.

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap-toggle';
$("#test-toggle").bootstrapToggle();
```

HTML:

```
<label>
    <input id="test-toggle" name="testtoggle" data-toggle="toggle" type="checkbox">
    Test Toggle
</label>
```

Webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    entry: './app.ts',
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.tsx?$/,
            use: 'ts-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.jsx', '.js']
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build')
    }
};
```

Webpack output:

```
[webpack-cli] Compilation finished
asset bundle.js 199 KiB [emitted] [minimized] (name: main) 1 related asset
modules by path ../node_modules/ 532 KiB
  modules by path ../node_modules/bootstrap/ 73.6 KiB 13 modules
  ../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js 281 KiB [built] [code generated]
  ../node_modules/bootstrap-toggle/js/bootstrap-toggle.js 5.41 KiB [built] [code generated]
modules by path ./ 632 b
  modules by path ./*.ts 632 b
    ./app.ts 632 bytes [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.4.0 compiled successfully in 5743 ms
```

The versions I'm using:

```
"@types/bootstrap": "^5.0.0",
"@types/bootstrap-toggle": "^2.2.1",
"@types/jquery": "^3.5.4",
"bootstrap": "^3.4.1",
"bootstrap-toggle": "^2.2.2",
"jquery": "^3.5.1",
"ts-loader": "^8.0.11",
"typescript": "^4.0.5",
"webpack": "^5.4.0"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my page was loading an external JQuery library aswell as loading my bundle.js which I had forgotten to remove during testing.

This then gave me a workable error that JQuery was undefined so I went into the library and added a wrapper which I took from another JQuery plugin.

```
(function(factory){
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd){
        define(['jquery'], factory);
    } else if (typeof module === 'object' && typeof module.exports === 'object') {
        module.exports = factory(require('jquery'));
    } else {
        factory(jQuery);
    }
} (function(jQuery) {

// ... boostrap-toggle code

return jQuery.bootstrapToggle;}));
```

And that's it all working fine.